# Connecting to an instance of SQL from TFS administration console throws connectivity error?

Tags: sql-server, tfs, sql-server-2012, tfsbuild

I am trying to connect the instance of the sql server 2012 which is getting connected from management studio and anywhere but while configuring tfs on system when I put the instance name then it throws error:

> F255049: . Verify that you have entered the correct name for the server, including the instance name, that the server you are attempting to connect to is online, and that you have the required permissions to connect. If you are attempting to connect to the remote SQL Server instance, then verify that it is configured to allow remote connections, that TCP/IP protocol is both enabled and configured to use port 1433 (default), and that Windows Firewall does not block this port

Now I have done everything i.e. turning off the firewall, enabling TCP/IP, named pipelines etc but nothing working and it remains the same. 
Why?

I am configuring the TFS on the same server and the same instance name is getting connected in management studio.

Comment: how do you connect to sql from tfs? try with . or 127.0.0.1 or PCname

Comment: I tried PC name, instance name, server name and combination... also the ip address but nothing works

Comment: Any solutiuon because it's been 2 days since I am trying to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

On TFS Side you can check :

- Check if you are the member of the **Administration Console Users**. else this error may appear.

On SQL side check following points :

- Incorrect SQL Installation order especially if you are using **Express edition**
- Database In **Recovery**
- List item
- Database Out-of-Sync – during migration to **newer version of TFS**
- The **Service Account** has been added in SQL Server.
- SQL **Database not running** or not reachable
- **TFS Proxy** not reachable